# Handle JTA exception using EclipseLink running on JBoss AS

Tags: exception, jpa, eclipselink, jboss7.x, jta

### Using

- Java 1.6
- JBoss AS 7.1.1
- EclipseLink 2.4.1
- JTA

### Updated Question

How do I suppress the stacktrace being thrown by JBoss when I handle the error on my own in a try catch with flush?

### Question

I'm trying to persist a entity using *em.persist(entity)*. If no database constraints are being violated everything works fine. But if persisting the entity violates a unique constraints exceptions are thrown. I'm using transactions handled by JBoss so the exception is thrown from another thread.

I've already figured out that I can handle these exceptions globally by setting *eclipselink.exception-handler* in persistence.xml.

My question is how do I catch and handle these exceptions locally?

Answer (score 1):

Calling em.flush() forces the statements to the database immediately and can be wrapped in a try catch block to handle exceptions before the commit occurs, though most persistence exceptions will mark the transaction for rollback anyway.

Comment: That is true, flush() makes the Exception being thrown and catched right away. But I still get big stacktraces logged by packages `com.arjuna.ats.arjuna` and `org.jboss.ejb3.invocation`. How do I stop this?